# Is there a way to replay a video in codenameone media player?

Tags: codenameone

Is there a way to get the codenameone media player to replay a video when datasource is an input stream? or is it only when it is a url or file

Answer (score 0):

Only by recreating the Media and replacing the component instance since a media is disposed on completion to avoid potential memory leaks.

Notice that since a stream can be only read once this would be a problem anyway.

Comment: Hi Shai...had anything changed since 2014? I want to replay a media file as well with an HTTP data source? Will using a nativePlayer help?

Comment: Using an input stream as your source would still have this issue as we can't rewind that. When you use a URL stream this would also be a problem. When you play a local file it isn't a big deal as creating and discarding a media file isn't expensive relatively to file IO.